# Pyserial with pip

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to install pyserial on my computer, I am on Python 3.11.3
I successfull installed pyserial with pip
But When I import it on a py script it tells : Import "pyserial" could not be resolved

Could somoene help ?

However when I pip show pyserial it shows it well :
PS C:\Users<MyUserName>\Desktop\Workspace\pyserial_impl> pip show pyserial
Name: pyserial
Version: 3.5
Summary: Python Serial Port Extension
Home-page: https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial
Author: Chris Liechti
Author-email: cliechti@gmx.net
License: BSD
Location: C:\Users<MyUserName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

Comment: More of that pyserial is in my python package on VSC

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Is the module you are testing pyserial with named pyserial.py? If so, try renaming the module, because the name pyserial [gets shaded this way](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap). Is the correct [python interpreter used in VSC](https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-set-default-python-interpreter-in-vs-code-76c38c210dc3)?

Comment: Thank you ! Yess my Python interpreter is the default one and was correctly set as you tutorial in VSC. More of that, I used to name my module pyserial and it use to work before but since, it didn't even if I tried everything (renaming the module, make a new python folder and copy paste the code, create a new virtual environment)